# Does Gix's command work like I 'want' it to work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do the options in [Gix's Command](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gix%27s%20Command) happen individually from each other? Or at the same time? I am particularly interested in the interactions of choice 2 with either 1 or 3.

For example, if both my opponent and me have a pair of 2/2s and I cast Gix's Command choosing options 1 and 2, do I get to put +1/+1 counters on a creature *before* it is destroyed?

Similarly, if I choose options 2 and 3, do I get to return my creatures to my hand? (I notice that the card does not target and I assume this is why)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each option will happen one at a time, in the order it appears on the card. So if you choose 1 and 2, then 1 will happen followed by 2. If you choose 2 and 3, then 2 will happen followed by 3.

So:

1. Yes, you will get the counters and your 2/2 (now a 4/4) will not be destroyed.
2. Yes, your creatures will be in your graveyard and can be returned.

> 608. Resolving Spells and Abilities
>
> > 608.2. If the object that’s resolving is an instant spell, a sorcery spell, or an ability, its resolution may involve several steps.
> >
> > > 608.2c The controller of the spell or ability follows its instructions **in the order written**.